# Thermostat and electric base board

Tags: electrical, heat

I have two different size rooms both with electric base boards and one thermostat that controls the heat. Since the thermostat is in the bigger room the smaller room becomes a sauna. I was told that I could connect another thermostat to the existing one to control the smaller room temperature. Now my problem is everything is connected and the smaller room thermostat is running together with the larger room thermostat . Is my connection wrong or maybe my thermostats are not good? Example: if I put the thermostat at zero in the large room , the small room thermostat wont work. Anyway, I would like to get some feed back ...![image]

Comment: Can you turn the breaker for the heaters off and post photos of the wiring inside the box for the larger room's thermostat?

Comment: We need to see this diagrammed out.  You wired it so the second thermostat is subsidiary to the first (which will actually work given your core complaint, but the layout is sloppy and should be fixed.)

Comment: I think Harper is right. Given the previous wiring that fed both heaters, there's no way the tstat for the smaller room would work properly since it probably only has power available when the larger room tstat is calling for heat. He needs to add an unswitched run to the smaller room tstat.